# How to create a wireless-to-ethernet router?

Tags: router, debian, bridge, udp, broadcast

I have a Debian machine, which I want to turn into a router.

It will connect via wireless to a access-point, where it will get an IP.

To its ethernet port, other machines will be connected. It will run udhcpd to give machines connected to the ethernet port, their IP´s.

This all works so far, including the routing tables I have setup.

The problem is, that connected to the access-point is another machine. It broadcasts udp packets and these packets are not routed to the machines that are connected to the ethernet port on my router. How do I resolve this?

Bridging the wlan0 and eth0 ports?

Comment: If its acting as a router, broadcast packets typically don't cross routers.  You would have to manually configure iptables to forward those packets.

Comment: Ok, how do I do that?